# Pry (Ruby REPL): How can I turn automatic echo off

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, irb, pry

Since Ruby supports parallel assignments and automatic value return from functions, almost every assignment and method run ends up creating an output when working on REPLs like IRB and Pry.

Normally I prevent this echo effect by putting a semicolon at the end of each line. For instance:

```
JSON::parse(very_long_json_string);
```

This normally prevents REPL echo. But when working with very large enumerables even one mistake can generate enough output to make a mess on the screen and put all my useful command history out of memory before I have the reflex to hit the break.

Is there a way to turn this echo effect off by default in Pry? As mentioned in the comments below (@Stefan), the same can be achieved in IRB by setting `conf.echo = false`.

Comment: In IRB you can set `conf.echo = false`

Comment: @Stefan That's great to know! Any way to achieve the same on Pry?

Comment: Try this
    JSON::parse(very_long_json_string); nil;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IRB there is:

```
conf.echo = false
```

In Pry you could replace the [print object](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#the-print-object) with an empty proc:

```
_pry_.config.print = proc {}
```

You'll have to store the old print object in order to restore it.

In both cases, the result of the last expression is still available via `_`

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 2mins :D

Comment: @Stefan This a great trick, I appreciate. Is there any way to reverse that? Like by saving or reloading the original proc? Like that I can make a custom Pry command.

Comment: Oh, I found it: `_pry_.config.print = Pry::DEFAULT_PRINT`